# Can I use Vuex to store my own class object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to share a object between components, class codes are there.

```
class IDE {
constructor(id) {
    config.set('basePath', 'static/js/ace');
    this.aceEditor = edit(id);
    this.aceSession = this.aceEditor.session;
    this.aceSession.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    this.aceEditor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
    this.aceEditor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
}
setMode() {

}
}
```

someone tell me use vuex, here is my store module codes.

```
export default{
namespaced:true,
state:{
    ide:null
},
mutations:{
    setIDE(state,ide){
        state.ide = ide
    }
},
getters:{
    getIDE: state =>{return ide}
}
}
```

when I try to get my ide object in store

`this.$store.state.global.ide.__proto__.setMode('ace/mode/java')`

chrome always tell me 

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMode' of undefined`

So I view my codes in dev tools

[image]

1. How I can to call my object like `ide.setMode()`?
2. Can vuex store object? 
   I find many examples of vuex use simple variable like number and string. none of use complex class object.

Comment: it would be `getIDE: state => state.ide`

Comment: @Matt
you are right, it worked, but I want to know why,

in
https://vuex.vuejs.org/zh/guide/getters.html

there have 
```
getters: {
    doneTodos: state => {
      return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
    }
```

doneTodos has return, I write my codes follow it, but why I cannot write return?

Comment: arrow functions without braces let you omit `return` - you can use `return` if you want, but the key issue in your original code is `return ide;` instead of `return state.ide;`

Comment: @Matt Thank you, it works, you are awesome